# How this function is toggling between classes if it just has the function to toggle to the active class?

Tags: javascript, css

This code is to show a burger menu af a header when using a mobile device.
When you click the button the menu slides down, and if you click again the menu slides up, but the way the code is written everytime you click the button it should keep the menu down, but for some reason it is sliding up and down.
This is the right behavior, my question is how this code is doing the slide up of the menu.
Can someone explain?

The JS code:

```
     function navSlide () {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.links-header');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('links-header-active')
    })
}

navSlide ();

The html code:

<header>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="logo-header">
        <img class="logo-lorem" src="./imagens/Grupo 105.png" alt="">   
    </div>
        <nav class="links-header">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>      
        </nav>
        
        <button>Lorem ipsum</button>
</header>
```

The css Code:

```
    .burger{
    display: none;
}

.burger div{
    width: 28px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color:white;
    margin: 8px;
}

@media (max-width:960px){
    .links-header{
        position: absolute;
        height: 11rem;
        top: 6rem;
        background-color: #2570b7b6;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items:center;
        width:50%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .burger div{
        margin-left: 5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .links-header a{

        width: 100%;
        margin: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .burger{
        display: block;
    }

    .logo-header{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`classList` is a property that returns a `DOMTokenList` which has a [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method.

> The toggle() method of the DOMTokenList interface removes a given token from the list and returns false. If token doesn't exist it's added and the function returns true.

**UPDATE**
Your `.links-header` element is initially hidden by this CSS:

```
transform: translateX(-100%);
```

Now, your CSS does not include `.links-header-active`. I can only assume what you shared is incomplete, and that it has styles to reverse the `transform: translateX(-100%)`.

**UPDATE 2**

You asked:

> but how does it go back to the "hidden" class when it is clicked a second time? the way it is code whenever you click it should toggle to the "active" class

Well, the way it was coded is that when the user clicks on the `burger` element, it toggles on the element's `links-header-active` class (ie, adds that class since it didn't have it to begin with), and when the user clicks it again, it toggles if off (ie, removes it). As mentioned above, the [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) adds the class when it is not there, or removes it when it is there (hence the term toggle).

Comment: but how does it go back to the "hidden" class when it is clicked a second time? the way it is code whenever you click it should toggle to the "active" class

Comment: `nav` in your js points to an element with a class `links-header` which is not shown in the HTML you shared. So it looks like the code you shared isn't complete